# Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int Vector Template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I've been told to do this assignment in a certain way.  To make a template of unsigned int by default for bitarray, and the vector holds it, but now I get the error C4430.

```
#include <vector>


template<class IType = unsigned int>
class BitArray {
private:
    size_t numbits;
    size_t capacity;
    vector<IType>  bits;
}
```

Comment: `std::` missing before `vector` ?? Where do you use this class?

Comment: You should also have `#include <cstdlib>` and `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write

```
std::vector<IType>  bits;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class IType = unsigned int>
class BitArray {
private:
    size_t numbits;
    size_t capacity;
    std::vector<IType>  bits; // <- add std:: before vector
}; // <- you must add a semicolon
```